# Combination of RowBox and SuperscriptBox create a new line "\n"?

Tags: bugs, formatting, boxes

Given the following code:

```
test[p_] := 
 With[{str = If[p > 0, "+", "-", "+"]}, 
  DisplayForm@
   RowBox[{DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["J", "P"]], "=", 
     ToString[DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["3/2", str]]]}]]
```

I expect an output like

$$J^P=3/2^\pm$$

depending on the sign of $p$.

However, I get the following output:

```
RowBox[List[DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["J","P"]],"=","   +\n3/2"]]
```

Why is the output so mangled? Note the "3/2" appearing last and behind whitespaces and specifically a linebreak `\n`. How can I fix this?

Version 13.1.0.0 Student Edition (64-bit on Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 1):

You have a superfluous "ToString". Without this:

```
test[p_] := 
 With[{str = If[p > 0, "+", "-", "+"]}, 
  DisplayForm@
   RowBox[{DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["J", "P"]], "=", 
     DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox["3/2", str]]}]]

test[1]
```

[image]